# Is there any tool to convert pdf to ppt/odp slides in Linux/ Ubuntu offline?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, presentation, pdftk

I am looking for a tool that converts PDF into PPT files or supports any tweak to import PDF files into LibreOffice-impress, LibreOffice-Draw imports the PDF but that does not do the job. So far I am trying to use a workaround called pdftk+pdfchain to burst the pages of the PDF file into single page PDF files and then converting the single page PDF files into images using ImageMagic and importing them into a PPT slide.

Comment: Possibly related to http://superuser.com/questions/268244/how-to-convert-pdf-to-ppt-or-odp

Comment: as Nick Weinberg suggested, the `gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -sOutputFile='page-%00d.jpg' YOURFILE.pdf` command almost did the job that is to burst and then convert the pages to pictures, then just to import them to Libreoffice Impress, job done :)

Comment: This question is increasingly relevant as the Linux version of MS Teams only allows the sharing of your entire screen, and not a single window...unless you have a set of powerpoint slides, which have special support. Neither of the two answers below provide a fully scripted solution.

Comment: Similar question on different sites: ■ [ms office - Converting PDF to Powerpoint, importing each slide as a singular picture - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/366417) ■ [libreoffice - Is there any tool to convert pdf to ppt/odp slides in Linux/ Ubuntu offline? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/797836) ■ [microsoft powerpoint - How to convert PDF to PPT or ODP? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/268244) ■ [conversion - Export beamer slides to powerpoint/openoffice-impress/keynote editable format - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21986)

Comment: Pavel's gs statement ALMOST worked for me. The sOutputFile clause produced page-1.jpg through page-9.jpg, rather than page-01.jpg, etc.  This means they don't sort. Not sure why. It's pretty clear what we asked for. I'll report it as a GS bug if I can reproduce it a few times.  Meanwhile, this is a good way to learn the 'rename' command.

Comment: This did it:   `rename -v   's/page-([0-9]).jpg/page-0$1.jpg/' page*.jpg`  using the perl based rename that came with Ubuntu 23.04 (and probably both earlier and later)

Answer (score 7):

Here's my take on it from personal experience.  It's a two-step process - convert the PDF into single jpegs, then import the jpegs into LibreOffice Impress.  It works best if the pages in the PDF are landscape already.

1.)  Make sure the package imagemagick is installed (`apt install imagemagick`).  Put your source PDF into a directory.  Then in the terminal, navigate to that directory and run:

`convert filename.pdf filename.jpg`

This will spit out a jpeg of each page in the PDF.  Move the PDF out of the directory to make step 2 easier.

2.)  Open Impress.  Go to Slide menu, Slide Layout -> Blank.  This will remove the "Click to add title" and stuff.  Then go to Insert -> Media -> Photo Album.  Click add.  Navigate to the directory with all your jpegs.  Select all the jpegs (if you removed the PDF from the directory in step 1, just press CTRL + A to select all of them).  Click Open.  The next options depend on what the pages in the original PDF looked like - if they were landscape, you can probably choose Fill Screen, but you'll have to see what works best for your case.

Comment: `convert -density 600 -resize 400% filename.pdf filename.png` worked for me to obtain high quality and good output resolution.

Comment: (For **ImageMagick** version **1.3.20**) If your source PDF is a multi-page document, a good **Step 1** above would be `gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -sOutputFile='page-%00d.jpg' YOURFILE.pdf` (as seen in a comment to the original question).

Answer (score 3):

**Works in LibreOffice ver. 4.3.3.2**

Idea gleaned from [this post](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-force-pdf-s-to-be-opened-in-impress-for-presentation/34820).

Open a new instance of **LibreOffice Impress**. Hit `Ctrl-o` (to commence the process of opening a file). In the ensuing **Open** window, go to the **File type** drop-down menu and select **PDF – Portable Document Format (Impress) (*.pdf)**. Then, select your PDF file of choice.

Said PDF file should then load into **Impress**. You can now save the presentation in whatever format is available...but, be sure to check the finished product if saving in a PowerPoint format, as the slides MAY get corrupted along the way.

Comment: With command line: `soffice --infilter=impress_pdf_import --convert-to ppt filetoconvert.pdf` to PPT OR `soffice --infilter=impress_pdf_import --convert-to odp filetoconvert.pdf` to odp format, etc. ([details of some issues with the final output here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633247/262081))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to convert pdf to ppt: online converting services, OmniFormat (very old software), etc.

Best solution i've used so many times is Able2Extract : http://www.investintech.com/products/desktop/able2extract/convertpdftopowerpoint/. Unfortunately it's proprietary software. You get free trial for like 7 days. But it's the best by far, for both Windows AND linux.