# LibreOffice Impress: Import PDF

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I downloaded a presentation and edited it in LibreOffice Impress.
Apparently I didn't pay attention it was only saved in /tmp - and it's gone now, but I exported it as PDF, which I still have.

Now I need to do some remarks on the presentation. Is there a way to open it again in Impress?
I'm doing small changes now in LibreOffice Draw - which doesn't let me export to odp or ppt.

Comment: "*it was only saved in /tmp*" Saving in /tmp is not the normal behavior of LibreOffice, so that bit seems rather confusing to me.

Comment: It was saved in /tmp by Firefox as I downloaded it. I opened the downloaded file in /tmp via the browser @user535733

Comment: One assumes you have already seen https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/154987/impress-and-pdf-import/, among the more recent iterations of this question.

Comment: @user535733 - checked it already. Doesn't provide any solution, just a different description of the problem

Comment: It provides the best solution that I suspect you're going to find: Each PDF page must be imported into Draw, then copy/paste into Impress. There is no direct import solution. With complex slides, this will be a mess. LibreOffice can often recover from tempfiles...but setting /tmp as your download directory likely eliminated that possibility.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [Is there any tool to convert pdf to ppt/odp slides in Linux/ Ubuntu offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797836/is-there-any-tool-to-convert-pdf-to-ppt-odp-slides-in-linux-ubuntu-offline)

Comment: Just for the record - copy-pasting manually each slide not required, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1365457/109174 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1434843/109174 .

Answer (score 2):

You can import it to Impress by setting the file type *and filter* manually when opening (*File* → *Open...*), usually through a drop down, to *PDF - Portable Document Format (Impress)*.

You can also use the command line option `--infilter=impress_pdf_import`.

Otherwise it will default to Draw and will open in a new Draw window as you experienced. This also happened to me and can be confusing.